# AngularFireAuth has no method 'createUser'

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I've been working with AngularFire .5 and Firebase (both of these I am getting from a `Bower Install`.

I started by sifting through the [Firereader](https://github.com/firebase/firereader/) code base, and have been working to update the methods.  So far so good, and I think everything seems to be loading ok.

I am able to initialize `$firebaseAuth` passing in my `firebaseio.com` url. Page loads fine.

I am using requirejs to modularize everything, and bootstraping angular manually.

Where I seem to be struggling, is knowing which directives to load, and when, based on numerous samples and docs all being in various states of completion (I totally get that).

My initialization of the app looks like this -

```
define([
    'angular',
    'angular-route',
    'ui-bootstrap',
    'ui-bootstrap-tpls',
    './controllers/index',
    './directives/index',
    './filters/index',
    './services/index',
    'Firebase',
    'angularFire',
    'Firebase-Auth-Client',
    'Firebase-Simple-Login',
    'underscore'
], function (angular) {
    'use strict';


    return angular.module('app', [
        'app.controllers',
        'app.directives',
        'app.filters',
        'app.services',
        'ngRoute',
        'ui.bootstrap',
        'ui.bootstrap.tpls',
        'firebase'
    ]);
});
```

Not sure if my requirejs deps need to be tweaked - like simple login or auth client require firebase?  That could be part of this.

The other issue is, I'm still learning Angularjs, and it could just be a bone-head move on my part trying to get it all working.

I've created a service to handle all of the authentication (based on the Firebase example, but trying to work it from nothing to get the hang of it all).

The service looks like this -

```
   services.factory('authManager', ['$rootScope', 'fbRef', '$firebaseAuth', function($rootScope, fbRef, $firebaseAuth) { 
      //authScopeUtil($rootScope);

      $rootScope.auth = $firebaseAuth(fbRef(),{
        'path' : '/'
      });

      $rootScope.auth = {
         authenticated: false,
         user: null,
         name: null
      };

      // provide some convenience methods to log in and out
      return {
         login: function(providerId) {
            //$firebaseAuth.login(providerId, {scope: 'email'});
            console.log(providerId);
         },

         logout: function() {
            $firebaseAuth.logout();
         },

         createUser: function(data) {
            var email = data.email;
            var password = data.password;
            $firebaseAuth.createUser(email, password, function(error, user){
                 if (!error) {
                   console.log('User Id: ' + user.id + ', Email: ' + user.email);
                 }
            })
         }
      };
   }]);
```

fbRef looks like this -

```
  services.factory('fbRef', ['fbUrl', 'Firebase',  function(fbUrl, Firebase) {
      // url can be an array or string
      return function(url, limit) {
         var ref = new Firebase(fbUrl(url));
         if( limit ){
            ref = ref.limit(limit);
         }
         return ref;
      }
   }]);
```

Maybe this needs to be `new FirebaseSimpleLogin`?

When I run the code, I get the following error -

```
TypeError: Object function (ref, options) {
      var auth = new AngularFireAuth($q, $t, $i, $rs, $l, ref, options);
      return auth.construct();
    } has no method 'createUser'
```

I don't know if I need $createUser, $firebaseAuth, AngularFireAuth, etc.  So far, nothing seems to solve the error, and allow me to call the `createUser()` function outline both [here](http://angularfire.com/src/angularFire.html) and [here](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/simple-login-email-password.html).

Sorry for being long winded (and possible really naive here) - just not sure where else to change things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expected usage for `$firebaseAuth` is to create an instance of it and *then* call methods on that object:

```
var auth = $firebaseAuth(ref);
auth.$createUser(...);
```

Comment: And as you can see illustrated in Anant's answer, the method is prefixed with a $: `auth.$createUser` vs `auth.createUser`.

Comment: I was overwriting the auth object immediately after setting it, therefor killing the function completely.  I will test the function, but I think this solves it - thanks guys!

Comment: Yep - getting the error back as expected now - I knew it had to be something dumb, but it's easy to get lost in declaratives etc right now.